# Do sufficient statistics always exist?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Suppose we have a family of distributions $p(x|\theta)$, and suppose $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are random variables representing iid samples from this distribution, all with the same value of $\theta$. A sufficient statistic is a function $f\big((X_1,\dots,X_n)\big)$ such that the conditional distribution $p(X_1,\dots,X_n|f)$ doesn't depend on the parameters $\theta$.

By this definition a sufficient statistic always exists, because we can take the whole data vector itself, $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$, as the sufficient statistic. However, in practice, a sufficient statistic is usually something like the sample mean, or the sample mean together with the sample variance, which takes the form of tuple of real numbers, whose dimensionality doesn't depend on the sample size.

**A minor sub-question**: is there an accepted name and/or formal definition for this notion of "sufficient statistic whose dimension doesn't depend on the sample size"?

**The main question**: does it always exist? That is, given a suitable formal definition, are there families of distributions where any sufficient statistic has to grow with the sample size? If such families do exist, what's a nice canonical example, and if they don't, how can we prove it?

Comment: Googel first, then ask. Among others, perhaps see [these lecture nores](http://stat.cmu.edu/~siva/705/lec12.pdf); Cauchy is problematic.

Comment: @BruceET I don't think "google first" is a very kind or sensible thing to say, because there are no obvious search terms to google for, and of course I did try. Those lecture notes do indeed imply an answer to my second (main) question, and so I thank you for them. They don't answer my first question, but still, if you would expand on the point they make it would make a good answer.

Comment: In case it helps other readers, the example given in those notes is the Cauchy distribution. They claim (without proof) that its minimal sufficient statistic is the order statistics (i.e. all of the data, sorted into increasing order), which implies there is no sufficient statistic whose dimensionality doesn't grow with the data. It'd be nice to have a proof, but I assume I can find one now that I know what I'm looking for.